# TinyMce как реализовать функционал который уже используется в tinymce для выделения текста

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Мне необходимо добавлять тег span для редактора в любом месте. А так же иметь возможность снимать этот тег с выделенного текста.
На данный момент это реализовано так.

```
function h_text(editor){
   editor.ui.registry.addButton('myCustomToolbarButton', {
        text: 'Скрыть текст',
        onAction: function () {
            let s = tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getContent({format : 'html'});
            let node =tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getNode();
            var a = node;
           
            while (a = a.parentElement){
                if($(a).attr("class") == "hidden_text"){
                let text  = a.innerHTML;
                a.remove()
                tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceReplaceContent', false, text);
                }
            }
            if($(node).attr('class')=="hidden_text"){
                let text  = node.innerHTML;
                node.remove()
                tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceReplaceContent', false, text);
            }else{
                
                tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mceReplaceContent',false,'<span class="hidden_text">'+s+'</span>');

            }   
            },

        });
```

}
Была идея с установкой тега в позицию range.startOffset, а так же удаление тега из этих же позиций. Но range не может определить на какой строке находится позиция.
Может где-то уже есть что то реализованное, мне не хватает небольшой подсказки для реализации. Пока что я просто удаляю ноду если нахожу ее, но это не всегда работает корректно.